# Get canonical equation of ellipse

Tags: euclidean-geometry

We have an ellipse with a circle in it. The circle is passing through the two vertices and through the ellipse's center. It's diameter equals `7`.
We have also an equilateral triangle which vertices are in ellipse's focuses and in the minor vertex (the triangle's height is equal to semi-minor axis).

How can we define the canonical equation of the ellipse in this case?

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the distance between one point of the ellipse and the two vertices is constant.

So the major axis length is $2d$, $d$ being the distance between the two vertices of the ellipse. Let's call $k$ half the minor axis of the ellipse.

We deduce from the diameter of the circle that:

$k²+d²=7²$, that is $d²=7²-k²$

$k²+(\frac{d}{2})²=d²$, that is $k²=\frac{3d²}{4}$

Thus, $d²=28$

The equation of the ellipse is then

$\dfrac{X²}{28}+\dfrac{Y²}{21}=1$

Comment: Thank you very much. But am I right that you denoted the semi-major axis as `d`? I'm asking that because you said major axis length is `2d`, but `d` is the distance between the two vertices of the ellipse. I think you meant the distance between the vertex and the center, didn't you?

Comment: And the second question is how did you know that `k^2 + (d/2)^2 = d^2`?

Comment: Both the distance between the two vertices and semi-major axis are of length $d$.

Comment: @Kremchik Look at your drawing. The triangle $OF_{2}V_{2}$ (O being the origin and V2 the second vertice (vertical one) is a right angle triangle, with size length $d$ ($F_{2}V_{2}$) and $d/2$ ($OF_{2}$), since $O$ is the middle of $F_{1}F_{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Starting with $F_{2}=\left\langle c,0\right\rangle $ and denoting
the intersection of the ellips, circle and $x$-axis by $V$ we find:

$$\left\Vert V-F_{1}\right\Vert +\left\Vert V-F_{2}\right\Vert =4c$$
and consequently:

$$E:=\left\{ \left\langle x,y\right\rangle :\left\Vert \left\langle x,y\right\rangle -\left\langle c,0\right\rangle \right\Vert +\left\Vert \left\langle x,y\right\rangle -\left\langle -c,0\right\rangle \right\Vert =4c\right\} =\left\{ \left\langle x,y\right\rangle :3x^{2}+4y^{2}=12c^{2}\right\}$$